# is there any web service present for authnetication using wso2

Tags: wso2

I am new to this wso2 evaluating wso2,
I am  using Identity Server I have  web application , want to apply web SSO feature using WSo2, I had check there are soap web service present in wso2 for UserAdmin,

https://server-info:9443/services/UserAdmin.UserAdminHttpsSoap12Endpoint/   using soap client for test , for dev have to write java client for request

but did not find any web services related WEB SSO for example I require authentication web service which will accept Username/password return some token information and using that token I can store  in session for single sign out

Is there any web service/ API in wso2 provide authentication? or what is best approach for implement SSO using wso2 for web applications.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for SSO with WSO2IS,  WSO2IS supports several standard ways to achieve it. They are,

1. SAML2 SSO
2. OpenId Connect
3. OpenId
4. Passive STS (for windows based applications)

From above,  most popular way is to use SAML2 SSO or Openid connect. Your web application also must support to talk with WSO2IS using above standards. Say,  if you need to achieve SSO using SAML2 SSO. You application needs to send the SAML2 Request and process the SAML2 Response in standard way as mentioned in SAML2 SSO [spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-profiles-2.0-os.pdf).  You can find a sample web application that has been implemented to work with WSO2IS from [here](http://xacmlinfo.org/2014/04/30/open-source-saml2-sso-identity-provider/).  This blog contains all configuration details that you need to do in WSO2IS side as well. You can even use the sample web application with other SAML2 IDP as sample web application is talking in standard way.  Also. if you are looking for Openid connect,  you can find another  sample web application from [here](http://xacmlinfo.org/2015/01/08/openid-connect-identity-server/) with config details.  I hope this would be a good starting points for you.

Comment: Thanks Asela for reply, how this security tokens works in wso2, suppose I use any authentication api in wso2, for example login using username/password to wso2 valid user and wso2 which will return me security token, is there any authentication api for to get token from wso2.

Comment: It is better to use openid connect..   there is `/token` end point, you can do a REST call and receive an id_ token.   It is in only standard API that is available .   More details would be there.  http://xacmlinfo.org/2015/03/09/openid-connect-support-with-resource-owner-password-grant-type/          If not you need to use  AuthenticationAdmin web service.  It is custom SOAP service which return a JSESSIONID.   you can find the WSDL from here  https://localhost:9443/services/AuthenticationAdmin?wsdl

Comment: Thanks, Asela ,I had go through the /services/AuthenticationAdmin?wsdl , it was helpful ,  using loginwithRemeberMe request I can get a cookie with  maxage, can I use that for web sso, how can refresh session? based on cookie timeout?

Comment: Asela, can you please give some sample code on how use the /token endpoint to authenticate a user with a username/password?